# How to Enable Virtual Display in webview_flutter Latest Version?

Tags: android, flutter

I'm currently facing an issue where **upgrading** the **webview_flutter** package to the **latest version** triggered an "Enable Virtual Display" error. I've **researched** this problem and reviewed the provided **[documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter)**, but haven't yet found a solution.

### The Error

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)